# How to filter set of numbers between 2 columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has `min` and `max` columns. I want to search for rows where a set of numbers are between this range of `min` and `max`.

Example: I have a set `(3, 4, 11, 18)`.

1. My query filtering could look:

   ```
   (3 between min and max) OR
   (4 between min and max) OR
   (11 between min and max) OR
   (18 between min and max)
   ```
2. But I wanted to know if there is a better way something like:

   ```
   (3,4,11,12) between min and max
   ```

   that will do similar to #1

I need this because the set can change between different searches. Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

The table in simpler context is class (classid, classname, minage, maxage). There are thousands of classes - so I get web request searching for classes with specific set of ages for example (3,4,11,12) where a user is searching for classes for ages 3, 4, 11 and 12.

Currently my query looks:
select * from class where ((3 between min and max) OR (4 between min and max) OR (11 between min and max) OR (18 between min and max))

Comment: Could you insert your set of numbers into a temporary table, and join that onto your table of ranges, with an appropriate where clause?

Comment: Could you post the table structure and examples of what you want exactly?

Comment: The RWTF is naming columns `min` and `max`. This will confuse only the sane readers. Please add your table definition and a snippet of data to illustrate what you intend to do.

Comment: I am trying to run the query from the java - hibernate. So I can't create a new table. The table in simpler context is class (classid, classname, minage, maxage). There are thousands of classes - so I get web request searching for classes with specific set of ages for example (3,4,11,12) where a user is searching for classes for ages 3, 4, 11 and 12.

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
SELECT * 
  FROM MyTable AS T
 WHERE EXISTS (
               SELECT *
                 FROM MySet AS S
                WHERE S.val BETWEEN T.my_min AND T.my_max
              );
```

Comment: thanks for the response and this looks good but how can I form MySet? Can it be done as part of the query?

Answer (score 0):

We would be able to help you more if you could add more information by posting your table schema. However, this sample query could give you some hint.

Sample Query:

`SELECT SampleValue, ColB, ColC FROM TableName WHERE SampleValue in (1,2,3)`

Comment: I have edited my post to give a sample of my table. What is the sampleValue here?

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to first create a table (once) and fill it with all possible ages (from 1 to 101):

```
CREATE TABLE Age
( allowed TINYINT
, PRIMARY KEY (allowed)
) ;

INSERT INTO Age
  VALUES
  (1), (2), (3), ... (101) ;
```

The use this in your search query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Class 
WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM Age
        WHERE Age.allowed BETWEEN Class.minage AND Class.maxage
          AND Age.allowed IN (3, 4, 11, 18)
      )
```

Comment: No, I can't create a table unless it can be done within a query.